# Integrating Slack with my utility

Tags: slack-api, slack

Assuming I have an on-prem utility for developers, and I want to send messages from my utility to Slack - what should I do?
I'm quite confused ...

On the one hand, it seems like I have to build a Slack application.

On the other hand, my utility is on-prem and it aims to send private messages only, so it seems like I have to ask my users to open
a Slack room \ channel for themselves, then I can send the messages straight forward to these chat rooms. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you need [Incoming Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)

Just [activate it on your team](https://my.slack.com/services/new/incoming-webhook/) and follow the tutorial "Sending messages" .